# Understanding Doubly-Linked List Node Removal in Java

Tags: java, nodes, doubly-linked-list

Clarification: The main question is which node is something like current.previous.next = current.next actually pointing to?

I'm using some sample code I found on a YouTube video, but really trying to break it down and understand it. Everything works as-is, I've added comments to each section to help me understand. Where I am really running into problems explaining what is happening in plain English is for node removal when the code start using previous and next in the same line. I'm not following exactly what it's pointing to now. I've worked through the code in the debugger, but I need some plain English explanation if someone wouldn't mind.

Let's say for example I've got a DLL that has 3,4,5,6,7. So I'm going to remove 5, which is the 3rd index. Here is the method for removal.

```
//Method to remove node at a specified position
public void removeAt(int index) {

    //If the head doesn't exist, break out of the logic
    if(head == null) return;

    //If the requested index is smaller than 1 or greater 
    //than the size of the list, break out.

    if(index < 1 || index > size) return;

    //Declares the currently used link as the head
    Link current = head;

    //Declare int i counter for use in while loop
    //While i is less than the index set current to the next node
    //and add to the counter i
    int i = 1;
    while(i < index) {
        current = current.next;
        i++;
    }

    //If the next node doesn't exist, set current...previous next?
    if(current.next == null) {
        current.previous.next = null;

    }

    //Else if the node before the current is null, set current to
    //the next node and then set the previous to null (I thought it
    //already was null??) Set the head to the current node
    else if(current.previous == null) {
        current = current.next;
        current.previous = null;
        head = current;
    }

    //If none of the above conditions, set current previous next?? to
    //the next node and current next previous to the previous node??
    else {
        current.previous.next = current.next;
        current.next.previous = current.previous;
    }

    //Subtract from the size of the list
    size--;


}
```

My main understanding issues come in when it starts using current.previous.next and current.next.previous. To me, current.previous.next is just saying to remain at current. If I have three numbers, 3 4 5 and current is 4, then previous is 3, so next would just go back to 4. I know this isn't right, but after reading other posts here, the Javadoc, and watching videos, I'm still not understanding what is going on.

Here is the other class:

```
public class Link {

    private int data;
    public Link previous;
    public Link next;

    public Link(int data) {
        previous = null;
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }

    public Link(Link previous, int data, Link next) {
        this.previous = previous;
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;

    }

    public int Data() {
        return data;
    }


}
```

I'd appreciate some explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Those write-accesses are to the fields, not to the value contained in the fields. To remove the current node, the pointers of the previous and the next node have to be changed to skip the current node...

Comment: @fabian I'm not completely following. I'll update the post to include the other class with those fields. I wasn't sure if they were entirely relevant or not.

Answer (score 0):

If node.next is null, it means that the node is the last element of the list. So if you try to remove the last element of the list, the element before the last element becomes the last element. Which is what this code does

```
if(current.next == null) {
    current.previous.next = null;

}
```

If node.previous is null, it means that it is the first element of the list. First, we have to keep a reference to the following element, define that the following element must not have a previous element, and then define it as the head of the list. Which is what this code does

```
if(current.previous == null) {
    current = current.next;
    current.previous = null;
    head = current;
}
```

Then to stay on your example
if current is 4, then current.previous is 3 and current.next is 5
so

```
current.previous.next = current.next
```

define that 3.next is now 5

and

```
current.next.previous = current.previous
```

define the 5.previous is now 3

So then 4 is not reference anymore in the list

Answer (score 0):

[Doubly link list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) (DLL) is a list that can be traversed in both directions as you already know. Each node has previous and next pointers to their siblings allowing navigation to both directions. You already have `head` variable pointing to the head of the linked list.

In the `remove` method you passed in the index of the node you wish to delete.

```
while(i < index) {
    current = current.next;
    i++;
}
```

Above while loop sets the `current` node to be the node we wish to delete. There are three cases to be handled at this point.

1. Current node can be the first node in the list. So `current.previous` points to nothing and `current.next` may point to next node if there is one.
2. Current node can be the last node of the list so that `current.next` = null.
3. Current node is neither head or tail of the list so that `current.next` and `current.previous` have corresponding values.

   ```
    if(current.next == null) {
      current.previous.next = null;
    }
   ```

Above code section will is the second point mentioned above. `current` points to last node. In order to remove last node you have to go back to `current.previous` and set its link to `null` so that `current` will no longer be accessible from the `previous` node.

```
 else if(current.previous == null) {
    current = current.next;
    current.previous = null;
    head = current;
}
```

checks to see if the current node is the head of the node. If `current` is pointing to head of the linked list, it does not have any previous sibling so that `current.previous` points to `null`. So `current.next` must become the new head of the list. With `current.previous = null` we set the `previous` link to null and set this `current` head as the `head` variable. Now previous node has gone. No references to it.

Third case is the above bullet point 3. It's handled by

```
else {
    current.previous.next = current.next;
    current.next.previous = current.previous;
}
```

where we want to remove `current` node. That means we need to link `current.previous` and `current.next` as siblings.

As a final note, your `Link` class uses public fields. They should be private and access via getters and setters.